# Symfony2 How to upload files Product->getPicture() on new record return null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, vichuploaderbundle

I try to use Symfony2 bundle VichUploaderBundle. When I use a record which is saved in database and request `Product->getPicture()` I receive uploaded file information. But when I try to create it

```
$product = new Product();
$product->getPicture()
```

I get null object and can not upload files.
My product class.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="CreLabs\Bundle\ProductBundle\Entity\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 */
class Product {

    use ORMBehaviors\Translatable\Translatable;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $sku;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2)
     */
    protected $price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float", scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $msrp_price;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/jpeg" })
     */
    protected $picture;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CreLabs\Bundle\SettingBundle\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\CreLabs\Bundle\SettingBundle\Entity\Manufacturer", inversedBy="products")
     * @JoinColumn(name="manufacturer_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="cascade")
     * @Assert\NotNull()
     */
    protected $manufacturer;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $created_at;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $updated_at;
```

How I try to use on new record

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$product = new Product();

        $file = $product->getPicture();
        $fileName = md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
        $file->move(
            $productDirectory,
            $fileName
        );
$product->setPicture($fileName);
```

Exception on guessExtension

Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be anything else than `null` for new `Product` instance if `picture` property is not set to anything yet? And what you mean by *you can't upload because of this*. You're picture property is string by the way. Not object.

Comment: Just follow instructions in *Usage* guide on VichUploaderBundle's site https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md

Comment: Yes for new Product picture property not set yet. Upload only works for update record, but not in new record creation

Answer (score 0):

Found problem

```
$imageFile = $request->files->get('form')['imageFile']['file'];
$product->setImageFile($imageFile);
```

Now files can upload and when create new record

Comment: On update I get another problem "The file could not be found."
And solved :) Thank you very much :)